# Javascript 2d for loop doesn't iterate through the final value of the outer loop

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop that behaves differently depending on what type of input it has. The logic that changes its behavior can't effect the problem that I am having. Here is my code, then I will explain the problem.

```
propagateForward(input)
    {
        for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
        {
            this.NN[0][i] = input[i];
        }

        for(let i = 0; i < this.NN.length-1; i++)
        {
            //The problem occurs between the next two console.logs when the neural network is not
            //the Actor agent, but is instead the critic agent. In the console "outside" will print
            //and "inside" won't print. Whereas they both should print.
            if(i == this.NN.length-2 && !this.isActor) console.log("outside");
            for(let j = 0; j < this.NN[i+1].length-1; j++)
            {
                if(i == this.NN.length-2 && !this.isActor) console.log("inside");
                var weightsSum = 0;
                for(let r = 0; r < this.NN[i].length; r++)
                {
                    if(r == this.NN[i].length-1 && i != 0) 
                    {
                        weightsSum += this.NN[i][r];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var NodeVal = this.NN[i][r];
                        weightsSum += this.weights[i][r][j] * NodeVal;
                    }
                }
                if(i == this.NN.length-2) 
                {
                    if(!this.isActor) console.log(weightsSum);
                    this.NN[i+1][j] = weightsSum;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(this.isActor) this.NN[i+1][j] = tanh(weightsSum);
                    else
                    {
                        this.NN[i+1][j] = ReLU(weightsSum);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(this.isActor)
        {
            this.NN[this.NN.length-1] = softMax(this.NN[this.NN.length-1]);
        }
        return this.NN[this.NN.length-1];
    }
```

It is the propagate forward for a neural network. This question is related to my bug with the for loop and not have anything to do with NN. I need to calculate the last layer of the Critic neural network, but 'i' will not loop to i = 2 which is the last possible idx inside of the inner loop. I have console log on the outside. When I run the program it only detects i = 2 on the outside loop, but can't access it on the inside loop. Thus the console of my program reads:

```
outside
outside
outside
outside
outside
outside
outside
outside
outside
outside
...
```

I want it to say outside and inside.

The only thing in between the two points where I am printing the same information from and getting different results is the declaration of the inner for loop. It works fine when the boolean this.isActor = true (It calculates the actor network just fine). The boolean this.isActor is the only difference between when it works and doesn't work. Neither of the console.log lines where I am testing are being affected by any if statements.

Given that this.NN.length = 4
Question: Why is the inner for loop not able to access i = 2, but the outer for loop can access i = 2?

Comment: Your messages don't give you any debugging information, add `this.NN` to see what's in the object. This might give you an idea why inner loop doesn't produce any messages.

Comment: @vanowm I figure out problem now thank you